# empty ’thebibliography' environment

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, errors

I get this error and I really don't know how to handle it.
I saw similar questions here and I've tried the solutions, but it didn't work.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn]{book} %{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}    

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{Bibliografy}

\end{document}
```

Bib-file:

```
@article{wikipedia1,
title = "Scripting language",
author = "[1]",
url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language"
}
```

ERROR - message:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 902--904

[47] (/tmp/.thesis.tex.bbl [48]
Chapter 5.

Package natbib Warning: Empty `thebibliography' environment on input line 8.
```

What should I do?
Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) does this help? [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/579)

Comment: What does `Bibliografy.bib` contain? Also, insert `\usepackage` after `\documentclass` and you're short a `\begin{document}`. In fact, while we're on the topic of sorting out the details, could you please provide us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) - something that we can copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what your problem is. We don't have `Bibliografy.bib`, nor do we know which compile sequence you're following...

Comment: Do you have any `\cite` commands in your document? Did you run BibTeX?

Comment: @Werner I've just edited my post, hopfuly is enough or I could send my .tex and .bib files

Comment: @Mico I don't have any \cite commands, but my .bib file was compiled withoud errors.

Comment: @Paul: Then you need to call `\nocite{*}` at least...

Comment: If I use this `.bib` file and the code from above, in conjunction with `\cite{wikipedia1}`, I get an error message about an incompatibility with author-year citation style

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you don't provide any `\cite` commands, then BibTeX (and LaTeX) won't know which entries in `Bibliografy.bib` to typeset: All of them? Just a few of them -- and, if so, which ones?

The consequence of having a `\bibliography` directive but no `\cite` commands is the warning -- not an *error*, by the way, "just" a warning -- about

```
Empty thebibliography environment on input line <line number>
```

or its `natbib`-based equivalent, *viz.*,

```
Package natbib Warning: Empty `thebibliography' environment on input line <line number>
```

The upshot: Do provide `\cite` commands!

By the way, if you want *all* entries in the bib file to be typeset but, for some reason, do not want to `\cite` the entries explicitly, you could type

```
\nocite{*}
```

prior to executing `\bibliography{Bibliografy}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} %{scrartcl}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{Bibliografy.bib}
@misc{wikipedia1,
  title = "Scripting language",
  author = "Wikipedia",
  url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language",
  year = 2014,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}    
\cite{wikipedia1}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{Bibliografy}
\end{document}
```